# ¿Cómo usar Toast en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mensajes, android-toast

Alguno puede decirme como puedo hacer que mi proyecto de Xamarin.forms muestre un mensaje tipo Toast (como tiene Android)?

Estuve buscando todo el día y no encontré nada por ahora, solo notificaciones y esto no me sirve.

Comment: leyendo por unos foros intenta lo que dice el usuario **ryanfrench** en este [enlace](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7223/alert-message-using-toast-maketext-not-showing-resolved-as-unknown-identifier), espero sirva.

Comment: Lo intenté, pero me parece que no es compatible con Xamarin.forms... debido a que el código de este es multiplataforma y el codigo que puso ryanfrench es de Android

Comment: Tienes una librería muy interesante para todo el tema de diálogos: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La opción para crear algo parecido a un Toast de Android en  una aplicación Xamarin es la opción que comparte [@alex chengalan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897466/alex-chengalan)

Al usar [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/), se puede obtener fácilmente el enfoque tipo "Toast" tanto para Android como en iOS.

**Crea una interfaz en tu paquete common**

```
public interface IMessage
{
    void LongAlert(string message);
    void ShortAlert(string message);
}
```

**Sección Android**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageAndroid))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class MessageAndroid : IMessage
    {
        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**sección iOS**

En iOs no hay una solución nativa como `Toast`, por lo que se necesita realizar una implementación propia.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageIOS))]
namespace Bahwan.iOS
{
    public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void dismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que en cada plataforma, tenemos que registrar nuestras clases con  [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/).

Ahora puede acceder al servicio de "Toast" en cualquier lugar de nuestro proyecto.

```
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert(string message); 
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(string message);
```

Otras opciones serían:

https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: Sí, esto ya lo había resuelto hace ya mucho tiempo y lo hice de la misma forma que la respuesta... gracias!